# Prove $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}\limsup f_{n}dx \geq \limsup\int_{\mathbb{R}}dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose that $f_{n}: \mathbb{R}^{d} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a sequence of measurable functions that converge to a measurable function $f$ mM-almost everywhere. In addition, suppose
that there is a non-negative measurable function $F$ such that 
$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}F dx < \infty$ and $|f_{n}| \leq F$ for all $n$.

Prove that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}\limsup f_{n}dx \geq \limsup\int_{\mathbb{R}}dx$.

Then give an example to show that the above conclusion may fail without
the assumption of the existence of the integrable dominating function F.

Comment: Use `\limsup` instead of just writing `limsup` in order to get the proper formating: $\limsup f_n$ rather than $limsup f_n$

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  That was driving me a little bit crazy =)  I was trying to use a space between 'lim' and 'sup'

Comment: Are we allowed to assume [Fatou's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou's_lemma)?

Comment: for future reference: `\operatorname{lim sup}` similarly yields $\operatorname{lim sup}$, but can work with whatever text your operator needs.

Comment: Yes we can use the lemma

Answer (score 2):

For the first part, try applying Fatou's lemma to the non-negative sequnce $g_n=F-f_n$.

For the counterexample, consider a sequence of functions which "escapes to infinity", e.g. $f_n(x)=1_{[n,n+1]}(x)$.

Comment: Or similarly, $f_n = n1_{[0,1/n]}$